# Retrieve data in chunks in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I want to fetch the data in chunks (using a `select` query) like in first attempt from 1 to 50 records and in second attempt from 51 to 100 records.

Comment: What is the client?

Answer (score 8):

Use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`. The following query returns 50 records after skipping the first 50, so records 51 - 150 are returned.

```
SELECT fname, lname 
FROM students
ORDER BY ssn
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 50;
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-limit.html

Comment: what does 10 and 40 specify here.

Comment: i updated to match what you want.  Also there is a link to documentation in my answer.  It will return 50 records after skipping 50 records.

Comment: @MK. I have the similar problem here with table rows nearly 12M.  How do I write a query so rows are retrieved in chunk without explicitly specifying the range? I have to read `row=1` 1 to `rows=117051923`